# Product of a bounded sequence by a null sequence is a null sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose $\{a_n\}$ is a bounded sequence and $\{b_n\}$ is a sequence converging to zero. Show that $\{a_nb_n\}$ converges to zero.

My attempt:

$\textit{Proof:}$
Suppose $\{a_n\}$ is a bounded sequence then there exists a $B\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $|a_n|\leq B$. Suppose $\{b_n\}$ is a sequence converging to zero then for arbitrary $\epsilon_1>0$ there exists a $M\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|b_n-0|<\epsilon_1$. So we have $|a_n|\leq B$ and $|b_n|<\epsilon_1$. Then we have $|a_n||b_n|=|a_nb_n|< B\epsilon_1$. Since both $B$ and $\epsilon_1$ are real numbers we can let $B\cdot\epsilon_1=\epsilon$. Then we have $|a_nb_n-0|<\epsilon$ and thus $\{a_nb_n\}$ converges to zero. $\square$

Is this correct? If not what am I missing? Please help.

Comment: Looks ok. Except a typo. $|b_n| < \epsilon$ should be $\epsilon_1$. And maybe you need some argument for case B=0.

Comment: It is not quite correct. There is an $\epsilon_1$ coming out of nowhere a first time, then disappearing, and reappearing... Better keep $\epsilon_1$ everywhere, instead of sometimes $\epsilon$ and sometimes $\epsilon_1$. And change the sentence beginning with "Since both"

Comment: You could have also started with $B>0$ instead of $B \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Fixed the $\epsilon_1$ typo. Corrected version is now up.

Comment: Continuation of my comment: change the sentence beginning with "Since both" to: For any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\epsilon_1>0$ such that $B\epsilon_1\le\epsilon$. + answer to your last comment : you forgot to change your 1st $\epsilon$ to $\epsilon_1$

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh That precaution is frequent, but useless in the version of my previous comment. Note also that at least, we already know that $B\ge0$ by construction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Product of bounded and convergent to $0$ sequence is a convergent to $0$ sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/990536/product-of-bounded-and-convergent-to-0-sequence-is-a-convergent-to-0-sequenc)

Comment: Your idea is correct, but you haven't expressed it well. The object is to show that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is an $M$ such that for all $n \ge M, |a_nb_n - 0| < \epsilon$. So you should start with "Let $\epsilon > 0$", then use the facts about $a_n, b_n$ to pick a value of $M$, such that you can then demonstrate that if $n \ge M$, then $|a_nb_n - 0| < \epsilon$. Your proof needs to flow in that order, because that is how the definition flows.